# how to set an audio recorder to automatically accept mic input in html5 web audio api

Tags: html

Am building an audio recorder using the html5 web audio api for 2 days now...what i would really love to do and if there is a way.. hope so, to make the system have a default of automatically accepting microphone input with out the need of the dialogue box appearing whenever a user tries to click the record button...in other words if a user clicks the record button it just straight away records without the need of the dialogue box appearing asking for options of either accepting mic input or denying it

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible if the user hasn't set the appropriate option (if even existing) in his browser. If all web applications could access the input devices of the user without asking or informing him about it, that would be a major security issue. Just imagine every web application could access the user's microphone or other peripherals without asking - you obviously wouldn't be very pleased with that.

Comment: Please mark answers that provided a solution to your problem or helped you find alternatives as accepted.